# Return value of a Cell as value if true or false of a function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get a value of a particular cell as value if true or value if false option using functions in excel. the exact problem i have is as follow

in column A I have the name list of the students and in column B I have their birthplace. Now I would like to find out the students from a particular city.

The best solution i could find was to use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*California*"),"Yes","No")
```

But instead of "Yes", I want the students name from California of corresponding row.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you do just

```
=IF(B1="California",A1,"No")
```